How are demons relevant to the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem?
The following illustration appears on the Wikipedia page for the Grothendieck-Riemann-Roch theorem, as Grothendieck's comment on the theorem.

Why is the Grothendieck–Riemann–Roch theorem in hell?

By the looks of it Grothendieck would have made a pretty decent cartoonist. I wonder what treasures have been withheld from us with him not having pursued that path...

@Numeral Great question. Just a tip: there's also an SE page called History of Science & Mathematics (HSM). If you are interested in these sorts of topics, this is also a good place to visit

This can be explained by a translation of the German text, as well as Grothendieck's life at that time and in particular his political activism. Here is an attempt.

[Witches' Kitchen 1971] Riemann–Roch theorem, the latest craze: the diagram
$$ \require {AMScd} \begin {CD}
  K^*(X) @>>> K^*(Y) \\
  @VVV @VVV \\
  \operatorname{Gr} K^*(X) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb Q @>>> \operatorname{Gr} K^*(Y) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb Q
\end {CD} $$
is commutative! In order to give this statement about $f: X \to Y$ an approximate meaning, I had to abuse the patience of the audience for almost two hours. In black and white (in Springer Lecture Notes) it probably takes about 400–500 pages. A gripping example of how our thirst for knowledge and discovery lives out in a life-distancing ideological delirium, while life itself goes to hell in a thousand ways and is threatened with ultimate destruction. High time to change course!

The German phrase "zum Teufel gehen" here translates to "go to hell", but literally it means "go to the devil". So maybe this explains the devil cartoon here.
On the one hand, Grothendieck proudly describes his extension of the Riemann–Roch Theorem as a highly non-trivial and famous result whose proof requires hundreds of pages. On the other hand, he despises it, or (institutional) mathematics in general. The reason is that he believed that the wars at that time and environmental destruction were much more important and urgent topics. In fact, one reason for Grothendieck leaving the IHES were their military fundings.
For more details, I highly recommend to read a biography of Grothendieck. The short article Who is Grothendieck by W. Scharlau is a good start.

Life-distancing ideological delirium, that would have been the perfect subtitle for my PhD thesis.

You can still write an autobiography with that title. I also consider doing that.

This is really a nitpick, but it feels somehow wrong to translate Grothendieck's text without including the labels on the arrows in the commutative diagram; the content of the theorem is that the diagram commutes for a certain (non-obvious!) choice of maps.

Initially I didn't include the diagram at all. Someone added it, but not in a good way. I had a hard time finding the correct arrow labels. I think Grothendieck's drawing covers parts of them. Please add them if you find them. But in any case this is not central to the question being asked. This is not about what the theorem is exactly saying.

@MartinBrandenburg: I understand that the theorem statement is not the point of your answer, hence my "nitpick" disclaimer. I did not check the edit history to see that someone else added the diagram; apologies. The last version of the labelled diagram visible in the edit history appears correct to me but maybe there is a display issue I am not seeing.
